# How to list values of a column based on another column in power bi measure/dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two columns in a table

```
Ticket   ContactPerson
A         John
B         Unassigned
C         Harry
D         Unassigned
E         Unassigned
```

how can I get only tickets which has ContactPerson as "Unassigned" ??
Output should be tickets - B,D,E only and should not include the ContactPerson column which has values "Unassigned" as this is irrelevant for me. I can write Unassigned in Header itself no need to add extra column

**I want to see this column in my visual**

```
Tickets
B
D
E
```

**And not this**

```
Contact Person Tickets
Unassigned     B
Unassigned     D
Unassigned     E
```

Comment: How are the two tables Ticket and ContactPerson joined?  Measures tend to be numeric - is it a measure that you are looking for?

Comment: Updated my question... they are 2 columns of same table

Comment: Where do you want to see your result? In some visualization? which one?

Comment: Yes in a table visualization.. which shows tickets which are unassigned. I assume it will be a new column which i can show as a visual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show just those rows that have an "Unassigned" attribute value, you should be able to just filter the visual in Power BI.

[image: Filtering based on value]

For example the left hand table has all values, the right hand table is filtered to just "Unassigned", but only showing those tickets relating to unassigned

Comment: Thanks for that Daryl, but I want to hide the ContactPerson column in my visual and show only ticket column. Updated more details in my question above. - Thanks

Comment: I have updated the example to just show tickets, whilst having Contact Person only in the filter.

Comment: Many thanks for that... it worked as expected.